# Angular 13 app + api rest. Web.config configuration

Tags: angular, api, rest, iis, hosting

I am installing an angular application on a hosting that consumes a rest api installed inside a directory on the same hosting. This app has the particularity that it needs to be accessed from a QR. The QR is going to have this information: https://www.example.com/example1 Suppose you go there and see the page of example 1. But as many already know, if you don't put a certain configuration inside the web.config we get a Error 404. (IIS Walkthrough)

So the web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>

  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>

</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And the error disappears being able to access the page of example1.

The problem is that now I get a 405 (Not allowed) when I try to access the api. In other words, requests like https://www.example.com/api/token give 405. This is surely configuration. I'm going to investigate on my own, in the meantime if someone solved it and gives me a hand. Cool!

Comment: "I am installing an angular application on a hosting that consumes a rest api installed inside a directory on the same hosting", so what kind of hosting and what kind of REST API? Keep in mind, not all hosting environments support your REST API like your local machine, and you must make that very clear as part of your question.

Comment: it does.  I already solve the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be a conflict between WebDAV and the Web API application handler, you can try to remove WebDAV module from web.config to slove this issue.

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV">
  </handlers>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule">
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Will try this one. Thanks. I solved the problem by adding the # to the angular routing config.